# If $V:\{f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\mid f''(x)-4f'(x)+4f(x)=0\}$, then the derivative $D(f)=f'$ should be define on $\mathcal C^\infty $ or on $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $V=\{f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\mid f''(x)-4f'(x)+4f(x)=0\}$. I know that solutions of $V$ are generalized eigenvectors of the derivative $D(f)=f'$ since $V=\{f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\mid (D-2)^2(f)=0\}=\ker(D-2)^2.$

My question is where is defined $D$ ? I guess it should be $D:\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\to \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$ but I really have doubt with this because since $f$ should be in $\mathcal C^2$, then $D(f)$ should be in $\mathcal C^1$ and not in $\mathcal C^2$. May be $D:\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\to\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ ? In other hand $$V=\{f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\mid f''(x)-4f'(x)+4f(x)=0\}=\{f\in \mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)\mid f''(x)-4f'(x)+4f(x)=0\},$$
so maybe it should be $D:\mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)\to \mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)$ ? But then $D$ would be defined on a subspace of $\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$ and not on $\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$. What do you think ?

Comment: The domain of $D$ is $C^{3}(\mathbb  R)$.

Comment: Why $\mathcal C^3$ ? Also, what is the range ? (I complete a bit my question for this point, because when I say $D:C^2\to C^2$, if $f\in C^2$, the $D(f)$ should be in $C^1$ only. that's why I think that $D:C^2\to C^1$ to avoid this problem of regularity)

Comment: It is not enough if $f'$ is defined on $D$. it should be defined and its values have to be in $C^{2}$ which means you have to take the domain as $C^{3}$.

Comment: Why $f'$ has to be on $C^2$ ? But still, if $D:C^3\to C^2$, then $D(f)\in C^2$ which is not included in $\mathcal C^3$, and thus $D(D(f))$ is not well defined.... That's way, I imagine that it should be maybe $D:C^\infty \to C^\infty $. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Yes sure, but if you take $D:C^3\to C^3$, then eigenvector may be not in $V$... And at the end, $V$ will not be (à priori) the kernel of $D$...@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: So at the end, the exercise is maybe not well posed, what do you think ? And we should rather consider $V=\{\mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)\mid f''(x)-4f(x)+4f(x)=0\}$ ? What do you think ?

Comment: I guess so. I think you can take the domain as $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Do you agree that if we don't take $C^\infty $, the approche will fail ?